# Can the working directory be set in the project (.vcproj) file?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, solution, working-directory, vcproj

I have a script that generates a .sln file and a few .vcproj files for visual studio 2005.   I need to set the WorkingDirectory option but its specified in the .user file. A file we cannot currently generate. I found the [vcproj file definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2208a1f2(VS.80).aspx) at msdn, but it seems that this option cant be set from there.

**How does one specify "Configuration Properties->Debugging->Working Directory" from the .sln or .vcproj file?**

Comment: I think it is ridiculous that there is no simple solution yet to this problem. You are not supposed to commit your .user files to a VCS either, so this problem scales to non-generated solutions.

Comment: We fell back to using a *please-run-me-after-checkout* script. But like Alan BcBee's answer, it feels overly hacky. It makes the perfectionist in me a bit sad every time I see the file. Still hunting for a decent solution. :)

Comment: See [change the working directory through VC++ property sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43825112/12447766).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After you change your settings, and close the sln you will get a user file named something like:

`Project_Name.vcproj.Domain.user_name.user`

Change it to:
`Project_Name.vcproj.user` and commit.

The next person who checks out the code will use this user file to create their user specific one.

Comment: You may wish to clear values of fields like 'RemoteMachine' in this file before placing it in the repo.

Answer (score 3):

Change from my comment. I did find the property:

[VCDebugSettings.WorkingDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcdebugsettings.workingdirectory.aspx)

Use Visual Studio Extensibility to create an add-in or macro that calls this method. You should be able to hook into a BeforeCompile event or something to set it.

Not an easy answer, but doable.