# Is it possible to change the working directory through VC++ property sheet?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm planning on creating a few related C++ projects which will all have several settings in common (output path, exe naming convention, intermediate directory, ...) and I've managed to set most of the ones I need except the working directory:

[image]

It's set to $(ProjectDir) by default but I want that to be $(OutDir) instead and I was hoping to achieve this through a Property Sheet.

Unfortunately the property sheet itself (not the property pages of the project shown above) doesn't seem to contain a "Debugging" section:

[image]

Is it possible to override the Working Directory value using a property sheet in VS 2015 Community Edition (Update 3)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the working directory be set in the project (.vcproj) file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846180/can-the-working-directory-be-set-in-the-project-vcproj-file)

Comment: @Derek Incorrect duplicate, I was asking about property sheets specifically, not the vcproj.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, these settings are normally stored in the `foo.vcxproj.user` file (if changed from the defaults), but can be put in a property sheet instead. Putting this in your property sheet should do what you want:

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Debugging Properties">
    <LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>$(OutDir)</LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>
    <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Adding this to the vcxproj seemed to work for me.

NOTE: I had to specify one property group for each of Release|x64, Debug|x64 etc. It didn't seem to work for me without the conditions.

Comment: @Derek It worked for both configurations (Debug, Release) in my case. It may depend on where you put the `PropertyGroup` in `.vcxproj`.